# Seeking GIS Navigation App for High Accuracy Data?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, android, navigation, mobile-gis

Are there any mobile GIS applications that I can use to navigate to high accuracy data on android?

1. I would like to load layers - a .shp or .kml and use the map to navigate to points.
2. It needs to be able to work offline.

Comment: You might want to look into Dual Frequency GPS, (both L1/E1 and L5/E5 bands) devices with dual frequency chipset can have higher accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Maverick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codesector.maverick.lite) to load kml files and navigate to them.

And I would like to try [QField](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.opengis.qfield) soon.